# Having trouble with MySQL division query (probably simple fix)

Tags: mysql, division

I'm trying to figure out the overall ratio for users.  There is basically two columns I need to look at to figure out the ratio, total_emails and total_hours.

```
SELECT sum(total_emails/total_hours) as ratio FROM table WHERE id= 1 LIMIT 0, 1;
```

This appears to adding the ratio up multiple times and I get a number like 8.45 when I should be getting something like .45

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT sum(total_emails) / SUM(total_hours) as ratio 
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1 
LIMIT 0, 1;
```